# "sudo apt-get update" keeps hanging at the same point

Tags: 13.04, apt, updates, translation

Since today I have a problem updating. Every time I try `sudo apt-get update` the process hangs at the exact same point.

```
...
Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-de_DE       
Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-de          
Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-de_DE 
Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-de    
Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-de_DE 
Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-de    
Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-de_DE   
Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-de      
100% [Wird verarbeitet]
```

I assume it is this line: `Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-de`

I do not what to do. I am running Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit, obviously german ;)

*EDIT:*

It did work (though very slowly) when I disabled `raring-backports` - so this may be the source of the problem. Again, it is very slow when it comes to "translation-de" - needs minutes until it contnues... Mabe this is the true problem...

Comment: Try selecting other mirror or Main server in update settings

Comment: I tried several servers. Still, it hangs here: `raring-security/universe Translation-de` or here `raring-backports/universe Translation-de`. Update needs around 5 minutes...